# could setUpClass extended in unnitest framework?

Tags: python, python-unittest

could setUpClass extended in unnitest framework?

define Base1 that extends the unnitest.TestCase, the Base1 has setUpClass method.

```
import unittest
class Base1(unittest.TestCase):

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    print('setupClass - this is Base1')

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    print('tearDownClass - this is Base1')
```

define Base2 that extends the Base1 class

```
from Base1 import Base1
import unittest

class Base2(Base1):

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    print('setupClass - this is Base2')

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    print('tearDownClass - this is Base2')

def test_default_size(self):
    self.assertEqual('a','a')

def test_resize(self):
    self.assertEqual('a','b')
```

I want the setUpClass in Base1 and setUpClass in Base2 executed before all test cases in Base2, could this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly call `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass`:

```
class Base2(Base1):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print('setupClass - this is Base2')
        super(Base2, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print('tearDownClass - this is Base2')
        super(Base2, cls).tearDownClass()
```

However, if you do not add to these class methods, you can skip defining them:

```
class Base3(Base1):, 
    def test1(self):
        print('test1')
```

In this case, `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` from `Base1` will be called implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

see the inheritance documents here
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance